# Subset a column using a threshold value by grouping the ID column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a df that was obtained from this (For eg.)

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B") 
Point_A <- c(10,25,30,40,50,60,75,80,90,100) 
Point_B <- c(21,32,43,54,65,11,22,53,94,15)
df1 <- data.frame(ID,Point_A,Point_B)
```

I want to subset the dataframe by taking the values < threshold (Here Threshold = Group  median of Point_A column - 7.5).

I am currently sub setting by taking the median of the entire column and subtracting the 7.5.

```
df2 <- subset(df1, df1$Point_A < median(Point_A) - 7.5)
```

But, I want to take the group medians (Medians for each ID. Here it is A,B) and then subtract 7.5 and do the subsetting.

Desired Output

```
ID  Point_A  Point_B 
A      10      21
B      60      11
```

For ID A, 30 is the median and 30 -7.5 = 22.5 and so only 10 appears in the output for A. The same applies for B.

Please guide on how I would go about doing this.

Comment: have a look at `dplyr` Here's a nice vignette http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html. You can also get use aggregate from base R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Point_A < median(Point_A) - 7.5,
                                Point_B < median(Point_B) - 7.5)
```

Or, as per @Frank suggestion in the comments:

```
mycond <- function(x) x < median(x) - 7.5 
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(mycond(Point_A), mycond(Point_B))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: ID
#
#  ID Point_A Point_B
#1  A      10      21
#2  B      60      11
```

**Edit**

I may have misinterpreted your initial question. If you only want to filter for `Point_A` do:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Point_A < median(Point_A) - 7.5)
```

Comment: I find `&` less confusing that `,` to separate conditions that must be met jointly. Either works here inside `filter`, right?

Comment: @Frank Yes both work inside filter. The usage of `,` is well documented in the vignette.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it in `?filter` regarding `...` as well, but just wanted to be sure, since it's a weird syntax choice. I'd also lean towards `mycond <- function(x) x < median(x) - 7.5; df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(mycond(Point_A),mycond(Point_B))` since for me retyping column names is error-prone.

Comment: Steven, I dont want to do the threshold for Point_B. I just want to do it for Point_A and take the subset based on Point_A only. When I use your code by removing the Point_B line, It says "incorrect length". How do I subset it?

Comment: You mean when you try: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Point_A < median(Point_A) - 7.5)` ?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Is there a way to just subset the df based on Point_A column only irresepective of what values are in the Point_B column?

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks so much. This solved it. I just applied it to a bigger dataset and I was able to subset it beautifully. :-)